# C# трактовка dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic

Существуют 4 перегруженных функции :

```
static void Foo(object x,object y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("object object");
}
static void Foo(object x,string y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("object string");
}
static void Foo(string x,object y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string object");
}
static void Foo(string x,string y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string string");
}
```

Метод `Main()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        object x = "X";
        dynamic y = "Y";
        Foo(x,y);
    }
```

Компилятор:

> object string

Но почему? Если переменная y трактуется компилятором как `object`? Следовательно, должен быть вызван метод с сигнатурой параметров `object,object`

Comment: Как раз нет. Почитайте подробнее про `dynamic` в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic). Во время выполнения `y` как раз таки и имеет тип `string` (в чем вы и убедились), так что, к примеру, Вы спокойно можете написать нечто в духе `y += y`, а вот `x += x` - не можете, так как в нулевом случае будет вызвана конкатенация строк, а в первом - будет ошибка, так как оператор `+` не определён для типа `object`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Ага, теперь мне понятно. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Ну, сам ответ писать у меня сейчас времени нет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Но я рад, что Ваша проблема так быстро разрешилась) Успехов)

Comment: если перегруженный метод вызывается с динамическими аргументами, то разрешается он во время выполнения, когда тип значения, ассоциированного с динамическим идентификатором, уже известен.

Comment: _переменная y трактуется компилятором как object?_ - откуда такой вывод?

Comment: @Grundy `typeof(List<object>)==typeof(List<dynamic>) //true`

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000, не понял твоего комментария, а все. Это не совсем корректное сравнение.

Comment: @Grundy `typeof(dynamic)==typeof(object)//true`

Comment: @Grundy Ну, исходя результатов таких выражений, я сделал вывод о том, что компилятор трактует `dynamic` как `object`

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000, [поведение `dynamic` сходно с `object` в большинстве случаев. Однако, операции которые содержат выражения с типом `dynamic` не проходят проверку типов компилятора.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic)

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000, Но суть `dynamic` как раз в том, что в отличие от `object` - правка наличия методов/свойств и т.д. откладывается на run-time, не важно при этом как именно скомпилировал код компилятор, если он добавил мета информацию.